# Django Update Field In Realtime & Validate

Tags: python, django, real-time

I'm presently creating a Django app where the user needs to input three required pieces of information: client, stage and purpose. These then combine to create a valid project name.

What I need is a field that updates as the user types to give a preview of what the project name will be. Is this possible?

I presently have:

```
class ProjectForm(forms.Form):
    client = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Client Name (lowercase only)'}),validators=[RegexValidator(r'^[a-z]+$', 'Enter a valid client name (only lowercase letters)')])
    stage = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPES)
    purpose = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Project Purpose (lowercase only)'}),validators=[RegexValidator(r'[a-z]+$', 'Enter a valid purpose (only lowercase letters)')])
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.add_input(Button('back', 'Back', css_class='button button--wide button--black', onclick="window.location.href = '{}';".format(reverse('home'))))
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('next', 'Next', css_class='button button--wide button--white'))
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                'Project Name',
                Row(
                    Column('client', css_class='form-group col-md-4 mb-0'),
                    Column('stage', css_class='form-group col-md-4 mb-0'),
                    Column('purpose', css_class='form-group col-md-4 mb-0'),
                )
            )
        )
```

Comment: Yes possible. How good is your Javascript?

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere, I suppose :)